# How can I override backbone.view constructor to use with own implemented registry

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Ok, I need to override `Backbone.View.prototype.constructor` to save `cid -> view` pair.

Wrote this but got error :

```
Backbone.Registry =
  items: {}
  register: (v)-> @items[v.cid] = v
  get: (cid)-> @items[cid]

fn = Backbone.View.prototype.constructor
Backbone.View.prototype.constructor = (options)->
  fn.apply(this,[options])
  Backbone.Registry.register(this)
```

But it make lots of errors in other libraries (like marionette and handlebars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the problem!

must use `fn.apply(this,arguments)` instead of `fn.apply(this,[options])`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i do it:

```
Backbone.Registry = function(opts) 
{
    // call backbone constructor
    Backbone.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this, opts);

    // your stuff
}

_.extend(Backbone.Registry.prototype, {

    }
});

_.extend(ReuseView.prototype, Backbone.View.prototype);
Backbone.Registry.extend = Backbone.View.extend;
```

If you want to override the Backbone.View globally then you need to do it before any of the other packages are loaded.